How do I send a file from a httpclient to a controller in C#?
I need to send a file from a httpclient to a http listener
Both in C#
The best suggestion I have found is to use IFormFile
However using that, the file is just null, in my controller
My listener code looks like this
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapPost("/", (IFormFile? file) => Console.WriteLine(file == null ? "no file" :  "there was a file")).DisableAntiforgery();

app.Run("http://localhost:5000");

This is my client code
var file = BuildFile();
using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("----FileBoundary-----");
content.Add(new StreamContent(file));

var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
using var response = await client.PostAsync("", content);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
Console.ReadKey();

MemoryStream BuildFile()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write("This is my file");
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}

Examining the headers, it looks, like data is sent
Why is the file null in the controller?
Also is there a better / simpler way of sending files than IFormFile?

You don't need a FORM post to send a file as bytes to an endpoint. In a FORM Post a file's contents are sent as the contents of an input type='file field. No field is specified in your code

Could you please share how are you sending the file?

What do you want to do? Just send the bytes? Or send them as a file upload? There are duplicate questions for both

@MdFaridUddinKiron the code is already there it's the second snippet

@PanagiotisKanavos, Okay I got it now, I am trying to investigate the issue as well.

The method is there too. It's not relevant though, the form field is missing

Yeah, I am just double checking what's going on, so need to investigate while debugging.

@Panagiotis Kanavos
Yes. I think that may be a better solution. Forget about IFormFile. Just send the bytes in content

StackOverFlow was very quick to close my question as a duplicate. To make the above code work, add to content with name and filename parameters. content.Add(new StreamContent(file), "file", "file.txt");

The IFormFile parameter in your controller action is designed to receive files uploaded through HTML forms. However, your HttpClient code isn't using a form for the upload. This mismatch is why file is null.  You could modify following snippet. var fileContent = new StreamContent(file); fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"); content.Add(fileContent, "file", "filename.txt");

@Torben You say it as if you see your question being closed as a duplicate as a bad thing. It is not: you've been pointed to two totally valid but different solutions, one of which is, depending on your use case, exactly what you need.
